# Storing and Retrieving Published APIs in WSO2 AM

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have a docker instance of wso2-am running with the published API which are working fine. However, when the docker instance is shutdown and started up again the published APIs together with the configurations are lost.

How can I persist the published API, map and display it accordingly when the wso2-am docker instance is once started?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic issue with docker where once the container is stopped all of its data is also lost with it.

In order, to save the data I had to use the **docker commit** command to save the previous working state.

Answer (score 0):

APIM related data is stored in the database(api related metadata) and filesystem(synapse apis and throttling policies, etc). By default APIM uses H2 database. To persist the data, you will have to point this to a RDBMS (mysql, oracle, etc). See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Changing+the+Default+API-M+Databases

To persist API related artifact (synapse files, etc), You have to preserve the content in the repository/deployement/server location. For this you could use a NFS mounting.

Also please refer this https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Deploying+API+Manager+using+Single+Node+Instances on information about doing a single node deployment